# Device to restart one computer using another

Tags: power-supply, arduino

I have a small crypto mining-rig (desktop PC-like) to which I can usually connect remotely for maintenance. Right next to it is an old laptop which I use for collecting some data from the Internet, also with remote access. (I use SSH on linux).

The mining rig often freezes and is unaccessible via SSH. Manual reboot always fixes the problem. The old laptop is very stable.

**I want to use the old laptop to reboot the mining rig in case of a freeze. How would you approach this?**

My handwavy idea is to connect wires to the reset pins on the motherboard:[image]

Then I could connect that to an Arduino UNO device[image]

Finally I would have to write some code to make this work. Keep in mind that I have no experience when using Arduinos. **Can you think of a cheaper alternative?**

Comment: does the mining rig respond to a power button click by performing a graceful shutdown?

Comment: @jsotola yes, exactly

Comment: @MichałKuczyński Based on this, the power switch click is preferable to the reset.

Comment: @jsotola good point! Thanks.

Comment: pins 6 & 8 go to the soft reset button ... one of them is probably ground ... the other is the soft reset signal ... the button could be replaced by an optocoupler with an open collector output ... the optocoupler could be driven by the arduino, or by the second PC

Comment: Does the reset need a short press or a long press?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are on the right road, assuming pins 5 & 7 would cause the computer to reset and restart. You can accomplish this one of several ways, Using the Arduino to switch a relay that shorts pins 5 & 7 for a few seconds and then it will restart the computer. You can measure voltage and if the reset logic is 5V you could drive it with one of the GPIO pins however the relay is the recommended solution. You could also use smart relay that will run off the laptop USB of the laptop. Without knowing your resources or skill set these would be probably the easiest ones to use. You could also power the Arduino from that connector. Just be sure your relay is not turned on for the first maybe 10 seconds (just a guess).

Comment: pins 5 & 7 may be hard reset, same as power loss ... data corruption may occur when hard reset is used

Answer (score 0):

If the power button performs a graceful shutdown, then in means that the CPU is not completely frozen (maybe the graphic card is, or the mining process, or ...) but not the CPU itself.

So you might try to have a script (executed at startup, using system.d if your mining computer runs also on linux) that monitors the mining process, and if the mining stops, restart the computer. You might in addition check if SSH between the 2 computers (laptop and mining) is possible, and restart if not, if you consider that no SSH while mining OK is an issue.

That way, no hardware required (ie cheapest possible solution) and no time down.

PS : without knowing what/how exactly it freezes, there is of course no guarantee that the script still runs, it would requiring testing (if the script freezes, then having it run as a kernel module might prevent it from freezing)

Answer (score 0):

The Arudino Uno is so cheap that it's the simplest solution if you want to use your old laptop.

I would not use the old laptop. I would use a Raspberry Pi. You can connect to it via SSH :) You can then trigger the reset input, or a power button input, using a simple python or even bash script to toggle a GPIO pin. The GPIO pin then drives an optocoupler that "shorts" the switch. The entire mining rig "rebooter" would be an RPI, a resistor, an optocoupler, and some wires to hook things up. The optocoupler's transistor will emulate the closing of the switch contacts. With two optocouplers connected each via its own resistor to a dedicated GPIO pin, you can control two switches, e.g. power and reset.

Answer (score 0):

2 to 10 buck wifi outlet.

Ping from your laptop. When ping drops after 5 minutes, send a off/on command to the wifi power outlet device (curl or similar http method). No need to program an arduino or connect to the device at all.

If you want to use an arduino, you'll need to setup a serial program to communicate with the arduino. But it's as simple as sending an "r" to turn on a transistor transistor 30 seconds. Trivial. Just Google "arduino serial transistor" for literally hundreds of examples.

Both of these are hard resets. It be better if you figure out why the miner crashes/hangs